# Getting error while sending emails from nodemailer from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, nodemailer

I am trying to send emails from my node.js app using nodemailer.
I dont know why but when I try after uploading the files in my cpanel and check, it send error as :

> "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 74.125.24.108:587"

while it works fine in my localhost.

I even enabled to allow less secure apps in my google account.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'XXXXXXXXX'
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});


var mailOptions = {
  from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  to: "myclient@gmail.com",
  subject: 'Code',
  text: "Hello",
};



transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent');

  }
});
```

Getting error :

> "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 74.125.24.108:587"

Comment: make sure your server allow to send smtp , check out are you able to send email or not ? https://www.smtper.net/

Comment: Can you tell how can I check that? i dont  know...

Comment: test it via link i have given : smtper.net

Comment: i got  this :"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c26sm10992497qtp.40 - gsmtp"

Comment: it works fine in localhost but not on a actual server , whats the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

use this way on server , allow your gmail account for less security 
https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/6260879?hl=en

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'XXXXXXXXX'
  }
});
```

Comment: i have already enabled "lesssecureapps" option and still getting the error.

Comment: have you replaced your code with above , what error you r getting ?